# Count indexOf characters from String variable

Tags: java, string, variables, indexof

I am currently working on a Java exercise. I am trying to count the instances of a character in a `String` variable which is entered using `JOptionPane` and counted using `indexOf`. I have this so far but it doesn't work as the count comes back with the wrong number of letters of that character type on testing.

```
String input_text;     
input_text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write in some text");
System.out.println("Index of e in input_text: "+input_text.indexOf('e'));
```

The user then needs to guess the correct number of letters in the string they wrote. I have tried various approaches for this but am stuck.

Comment: Do you know what `indexOf` does?

Comment: What do you expect the index of 'e' to be for the string " java_exercise"?

Comment: Write a loop and compare each character in the String to see if it matches the character you are looking for.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code a `String` to test. The option pane is irrelevant. 2) What was the input `String`? What did you expect as output? Why did you expect that? How did the actual output differ from expectation?

Comment: The option pane is very relevant as the user needs to input the string via some kind of interface. Which is required by the exercise.The Indexof doesnt work here as it is designed to find out the index of the specified character rather than the total number of times the character occurs. I dont have a code example which would be helpful here currently. Hence my question for some examples so i can work this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) function won't work here as a solution to your problem since it is meant to provide you with the index of the first occurrence of the required substring(a particular character in this case).

You need to loop through the characters of your string and count for the matches with the particular character.

```
String input_text;     
input_text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write in some text");
System.out.println("Index of e in input_text: "+ getMatchCount(input_text, 'e'));

int getMatchCount(String input, char charToMatch) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if(input.charAt(i) == charToMatch) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

You can also use the Apache Commons StringUtils' [countMatches](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function directly.

Moreover, if you intend to find the count of multiple(different) characters in the input string, you can rather create an occurrence count map for each of the characters present in the input string, so that you don't need to iterate through the entire string again and again when asked for the count of matches for a different character.

Answer (score 0):

> thanks for all the comments here i have managed to solve the character loop like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s1="this is a sentence";
    char ch=s1.charAt(s1.indexOf('e'));
    int count = 0; 
    for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++) {
        if(s1.charAt(i)=='e'){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total count of e:=="+count);
}
```

}

> I will now try and add the JOptionPane components :-)